# Waiting until threads finish before executing next step

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

I, at most, have two threads running at any single time. How do I wait for these threads to finish before executing my next step?

If I don't wait for them, I get a `NullReferenceException` when I check the values because they haven't been set yet due to the threads still running.

Comment: Have you considered using Async / Await or the Task Parallel Library instead of raw threads?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an article about them?

Comment: Here is a great example from microsoft https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you! Will read up, if I have any issues will reply. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would go with the Async / Await pattern on this.  It gives you excellent flow control and won't lock up your UI.

Here is a great example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2):

```
Public Class Form1
    Public Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(addressof Task1))
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(addressof Task2))
        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

        MsgBox("Done!")
    End Sub

    Private Async Function Task1() As Task 'Takes 5 seconds to complete
        'Do some long running operating here. Task.Delay simulates the work, don't use it in your real code
        Await Task.Delay(5000)
    End Function

    Private Async Function Task2() As Task 'Takes 10 seconds to complete
        'Do some long running operating here. Task.Delay simulates the work, don't use it in your real code
        Await Task.Delay(10000)
    End Function
End Class
```

The basic idea is to create an array of `Task` (these can point to functions that return `Task` also).  This queues up the "threads" wrapped in task objects that get run when you call `Task.WhenAll`, which will execute all the tasks in the array and continue after they all complete.  Code after that will run once every tasks completes, but it won't block the UI thread.

Comment: I've modified the example slightly to actually use `Await` on the result.  The MSDN example is more about Tasks than async / await, but they are very compatable.

Comment: Thank you! 

One thing I notice is that the async function returns a value. In the example's async function, I instead use a sub that calls another sub which doesn't return any value. How do I account for that?

Comment: I've updated my example a bit in a way that better shows what I think you are trying to do.  If you have a bit of threaded code that doesn't return a value just use `Task`, if it needs to return a value, use `Task(of ReturnType)` and `Await` the result as in `dim result as integer = Await SomeFunctionThatReturnsATaskOfInteger()`.

Comment: Delay is not a member of Task, can you please help?

Answer (score 5):

If you call join the main Thread will be wait that the other thread finished. I think the code bellow will be good to understand the idea.

```
Sub Main()
        thread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf countup)
        thread.Start()
        thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf countup2)
        thread2.Start()
        thread.Join() 'wait thread to finish
        thread2.Join()  'wait thread2 to finish
        Console.WriteLine("All finished ")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
```

See the links:
[General](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsw9f9ts(v=vs.71).aspx);
[WinForms](http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-53-multithreading/)

Comment: May work for console applications, but using this in Winforms applications will make the UI freeze.

Comment: If the OP wanted a platform specific solution, he should have tagged the question with the platform.

Comment: @VisualVincent I am using winforms, and this freezes my program indefinitely.

Comment: see the link in WinForm application
http://howtostartprogramming.com/vb-net/vb-net-tutorial-53-multithreading/

Comment: @BradleyUffner : I wrote that to improve explanation for future complications, since we do not know what the OP uses. But as he now says the application froze, he must be using Winforms or WPF.

Comment: @ruirodrigues1971 The example on that site is horrible.  It actually directs you disable thread safety checks with `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False`.  I wouldn't recommend anyone follow that example.

Comment: The link you provided seems old. It's not related to the OP's problem and I believe he knows how to use threads. One should _**never**_ set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to False.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and was a bit iffy on that... I am checking for illegal thread calls in my program.

Comment: @HighMans : If you start and join your threads in a new thread, you won't have the problem with freezing UI.

Comment: I *really* think Async / Await with `Task.Run` is the way to go with this one.

Comment: @Bradley Uffner you have to know what you are doing. If exist concurrency for the same resource  of course is wrong (CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to False) or you have to put a lock to protect the resource. Depends of the problem.
I think the best is also using tasks is more modern and easily, but also the solution presented with tasks is not completed (but i vote for that solution),  put person in the right way. But of course the thread ways is also correct, but you need manage in more detail some features.

Comment: Keep in mind that every thread you create has to allocate 1 MB of memory for its stack.Threads are heavy.  If you go that route I recommend, at the very least, using a thread from the thread pool instead of creating one manually.

Comment: @ruirodrigues1971 : Why would you set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to False and do a workaround for locking every object you want to access, when you can just invoke? Also, illegal calls from a thread is about more than just concurrent accessing.